# 4th Network Site Database Errors?

Tags: multisite, database, errors, admin-menu, network-admin

4th site created but not available in the admin menu or the my sites screen.

So the my sites screen /wp-admin/my-sites.php only shows three, not the 4th.

The My Sites menu at the top also only shows 3, not the 4th.

If I click to My Sites>Network Admin>Sites then I see all 4 listed on this page wp-admin/network/sites.php and can acces the fourth site.

Why doesn't it show up in all the other menus? Can you help me find the root cause of the problem and fix it?

I had previously tried to delete the site, and then re-created the site, but the issue remains. I also turned off all plugins, but the issue remains. I'm afraid that there is a deeper problem which is perhaps database related. Can you help me solve it please?

Comment: Did you create all 4 sites? Do you have super Admin privileges on the Multisite network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that was the problem. The site was configured with incorrect admin user information. The problem was solved by going to the user profiles and setting myself as a "super administrator" of the 4th site. Some how it had been created under a different user which was full of incorrect information. To make the site show up in your menu just go to "my sites" > "Sites" and you should see a list of all the sites.

On the right you can see which ones you are or are not listed as a user of. Find the ones that are missing your name, and hover your mouse over the "path" for that site on the left-hand side. You will see an edit button pop up, click it. On the new page you will see 4 tabs at the top, click "Users". From there you just add yourself as a user for the site as well (be sure to select your role as an "administrator". Then save. Your done, unless you want to remove an accidental user as well which is what I had to do, in which case edit their status however you see fit.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote was here, but this process worked just fine in Feb 2023. So I did an upvote.